# Why doesn't FutureBuilder return the Widget?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't get why this FutureBuilder doesn't return the Widget.
"TEST" is printed, so the ConnectionState is done.
"Null" is not be printed, but i think it doesn't matter.
So what is the problem?

```
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        print("TEST");
        if(snapshot.data == null) print("Null");
        return Container(
          height: 90,
          width: 90,
          color: Colors.white,
        );
      return Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 30,
        color: Colors.redAccent,
      );
    },
  );
```

i dont think it is the getData-function, because i got the data, but for case i leave it here:

```
getData() async {
return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(reference).get().then(
        (snapshot) => userdata = User.fromJson(snapshot.data()!));
```

}

In the logs i get the follow error:

```
1690-1704/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

but i think it's something different. I read i can ignore it. Correct me, if this information was wrong
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to return userdata?

Comment: What makes you think the Widget is not returned?

Comment: Yes, but the original widget is a lot bigger, so i posted a container. Both doesn't work

Comment: BTW, the closing brack for the if-block is missing

Comment: Because on the blue screen appears no white or red field

Comment: There doesn't look anything wrong with the `FutureBuilder`. Good chance the error lies in  how you are integrating this `FutureBuilder` in the rest of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Check that are you getting an white container.

Answer (score 0):

Change the container color from `Colors.white` to any other color

```
    return FutureBuilder(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        print("TEST");
        if(snapshot.data == null) print("Null");
        return Container(
          height: 90,
          width: 90,
          color: Colors.white, // If you change the color maybe the container get visible
        );
      return Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 30,
        color: Colors.redAccent,
      );
    },
  );
```